# Weight distribution in bucket such that minimum number of buckets are used

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, data-structures

I have n weights that weight{A1,A2,...,An} and i have to divide then into buckets such that minimum number of buckets are required and each bucket has maximum capacity of Cmax and Ai<Cmax and size of each bucket should be as close to Cmax as possible
Example:-
I have weight {1,2,3,4,5} and Cmax= 5
So, result should be ({1,4},{2,3},{5})

```
{2,3,4,5} and Cmax=10
 So, result should be {{5,3,2},{4}} .
```

other possible solution is {5,4},{3,2 } but this is not acceptable as.
each initial set should be as much close to Cmax  as possible

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this is NP-hard problem, so exact solution is guaranteed only with brute-force approach - checking all possible variants. It is possible for rather small problem size (`n, buckets < 10..15`) - there are `N^Buckets` variants.

Otherwise (usually in case of `n < 100`) you can try some discrete optimization methods like [Branch and bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) algorithm (stop searching when current solution becomes worse than the best already found one)